# How can I detect when the scroll bar reaches the end of a data grid view?

Tags: c#, datagridview, scroll

I would like to detect when the scroll bar reaches the end of a data grid view, so I can run a function when this happens.

I was exploring the `Scroll` event, but without success.

Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to use knowledge of the `DataGridView`'s height and the value of the `DataGridView.ScrollingOffset` to determine that you're at the end.

Comment: If you have the `DataGridView` in virtual mode, you would control giving it the content as it becomes visible so you would know when the last row visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you close... place this in your `Scroll` event and it will tell you when the last row is visible:

```
  int totalHeight = 0;
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    totalHeight += row.Height;

  if (totalHeight - dataGridView1.Height < dataGridView1.VerticalScrollingOffset)
  {
    //Last row visible
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way to do it...

```
private void dataGrid_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs scrollEventArgs)
{
    if (dataGrid.DisplayedRowCount(false) + 
        dataGrid.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex
        >= dataGrid.RowCount)
    {
        // at bottom
    }
    else
    {
        // not at bottom
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative solution:

Scroll event runs everytime the scrollbar is being moved. Depending on your use case, this may cause [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319620/c-sharp-load-rows-on-datagridview-scroll-bar-reach-end/58025866#58025866) or not so performant. So a better way is to run your check and function only when user releases the scrollbar by handling the `EndScroll` event.

However, you would have to use LINQ to access the `datagridview's` `ScrollBar` control and set the event handler like this:

```
using System.Linq;
public MyFormConstructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    VScrollBar scrollBar = dgv.Controls.OfType<VScrollBar>().First();
    scrollBar.EndScroll += MyEndScrollEventHandler;
}

private void MyEndScrollEventHandler(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
   if (dgv.Rows[dgv.RowCount - 1].Displayed){ // Check whether last row is visible
      //do something
   }
}
```