# How to get the position of the DataGridView Vertical scroll bar?

Tags: c#, datagridview, vertical-scroll

I have a DataGridView. How can i know when the vertical scroll reaches the end?

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26513196/6129872) code but it gives me inconclusive results. **How can i really access some info on weather the scroll bar is at the end or not?**

Comment: Can you tell me the purpose you need to know the scroll bar position?

Comment: This question is related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407869/touch-screen-datagridview-not-scrolling-to-the-end/37408214?noredirect=1#comment62324786_37408214

Ill edit this question and put some code

Comment: @Akanksha I edited the main question. Why did you deleted your awnser?

Comment: I thought it ws for scrollviewer... datagrid will b different..changing my answer... i thought i ws for wpf

Comment: try adding totalheight +=dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height
this might work, it did at my end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112791/discussion-between-akanksha-and-meme).