# C# load rows on datagridview scroll bar reach end

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm facing an issue that **only happens** when I use my mouse to move the scrollbar to the bottom of the datagridview. So, the problem **does not occur** when I click in this button:

[image]

My goal is to load 200 rows at beginning and then when user reaches the end of the datagridview scroll bar load more 200 rows and so on..

```
private void Home_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LoadRows();
}

// Detects if the scrollbar is at bottom
private void dataGridViewUsers_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    if (hasMoreRows == false)
        return;

    // The rows height is always 22
    int totalHeight = this.dataGridViewUsers.Rows.Count * 22;

    if ((totalHeight - this.dataGridViewUsers.Height) < this.dataGridViewUsers.VerticalScrollingOffset)
        LoadRows();
}

private void LoadRows()
{
    DataSet DSet = controllers.Users.LazyLoad(offset);

    if (DSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count <= 0)
    {
        hasMoreRows = false;
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < DSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        this.dataGridViewUsers.Rows.Add
        (
            DSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"].ToString(),
            DSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["name"].ToString(),
            DSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["mobile"].ToString(),
            DSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["signup_date"].ToString()
        );
    }

    offset += 200;
    this.dataGridViewUsers.Refresh();
}
```

What happens is that usually people grab the scrollbar and pulls it to the bottom.
[image]

And if I do that within my datagridview, more rows are added as expected but a strange behavior happens.

I have roughly 2000~ rows, and whenever I pull the scrollbar into the bottom at once, my scrollbar goes nuts Up & Down, Up & Down, Up & Down, until it reaches the total rows. It's like the scrollbar has life itself..or is in a loop..

Can you guys see in my code what could reproduce such behavior?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: AFIK, this is usually done with [Virtual Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by handling the `EndScroll` event of the datagridview's `ScrollBar` control instead of the datagridview's `Scroll` event. So only when the person releases the scrollbar, the system will do the check on whether it is at the bottom of the datagridview or not and proceed appropriately.

You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28617333/3526156) on how to access the datagridview `ScrollBar`'s event and instead of handling `Scroll` event, just handle the `EndScroll` like this:

```
using System.linq;
public MyFormConstructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    VScrollBar scrollBar = dgv.Controls.OfType<VScrollBar>().First();
    scrollBar.EndScroll += MyEndScrollEventHandler;
}

private void MyEndScrollEventHandler(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
   // Handler with e.Type set properly
}
```

Comment: If anyone else is seeing only a `Scroll` event handler instead of `EndScroll`, it can do the same thing.  Check `ScrollEventArgs e` for `e.Type == ScrollEventType.EndScroll`.

Answer (score -1):

Well  if i understood  you  correctly  you  want  for the  first time(On first  program run)  just load only  200 rows  not more  isn't it ?!  If  that's so  u should  use  LINQ :), if you  are  familiar  with it  u  can just  write like this :  ( I WILL SHOWV U  THE  PSEUDOCODE)   Some Data object".Select(p  =>  p).Take(200) //  If u  will  write  similar   LINQ  request  u  will get  first 200 Data  rows  from  your  database.

More  here sample u  can look  at  it

```
var something = someobject.
                     .Select(a => a.name)
                     .Take(200);
```

P.S. Unfortunately  i am not  familiar  how  well u know  C# LINQ  libraries  but  anyway  u  can use  google  to get more  specific info's  about LINQ.

Hope  this  will  be little  help  for  you  Good luck in coding  mate.

Comment: The question is more concerned with the scrollbar action than with reading more records, I think.

Comment: He  has  a problem during  the data loading,  i guess  he does not invoke  the  data  correctly when  he is pulling up scroll bar and  releasing it.... scollbar  is  heating  down  and  continues data rows loading, that's  why i have advised  to use  LINQ..........  Guess  he is using  old style of Data  Access Layer(DAL)  and if  he  wants so...... it means  he should  be more  specific  in for()  loop  how to manage  loading process.   I  think he  should use  LINQ  for that it is  more convenient  and secure.  Also  I am concerned  abour WinForm  why  he is  using WinForms when  we have WPF