# Pagination in TableLayoutPanel when Adding Controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a chat application using C# window form. But I have a challenge on how to load chat messages using pagination like what skype does that is assuming a chat has 1000 chats I need to first load the last like 50 messages on the TableLayoutPanel. Then when the user scroll  up the TableLayoutPanel the other chat (950)get loaded based on the screen size to improve the performance. Here is my implementation of my chat message app. Am using .net 4.5.2.  I want when a user open the chat with the receiver assuming they had chatted before like from last year. I dont want to show all conversation from last year. I want on the table layout to show previously chat like from yesterday not showing all chat from last year. So What I want is as the user scroll up on the tablelayoutpane the table layout pane get added previous chats. Eg if user scrolls like up to Aug 2023 what is displayed on the pane is chat from Aug to date not other previous chats.

```
 TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1 = new TableLayoutPanel();
        WsChatConnection chatConnection;
        string sender_id;
        Mdi mdi;
        ChatServiceHandler http;
        UserChatRequestModel userChatRequestModel;
        public frmChatWindow(Mdi mdi)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.mdi = mdi;

            http = new ChatServiceHandler();
            userChatRequestModel = new UserChatRequestModel();

         
            usersData = http.getAllChatUsers();
            basex = bubblePanel.Location.X;//bubble panel house TableLayoutPanel
            basey = 0
            tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            tableLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 0;
            tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = false;
            tableLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Visible = false;
            tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
            bubblePanel.Controls.Add(tableLayoutPanel1);
           


        }
        
           void loadUserChats()
        {
            IList<UserConversation> conversations = http.getUsersPreviousChats(userChatRequestModel);//this returns data in milliseconds.
            if (conversations.Count > 0)
            {
                
                IList<Conversation> chats = conversations[0].chat;
           
                int tally = 0;
                tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
                int row=0;
                foreach (Conversation chat in chats)//this loop is taking forever and freezes as the messages are many. I need a way to load conversation on user scroll
                {
                   CustomControl control=new CustomControl();
                   control.LabelText=chat.message;
                   tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(control, 0, row);
                   row++;
                    tally++;
                }
                tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
                tableLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Value = tableLayoutPanel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum;
                tableLayoutPanel1.ScrollControlIntoView(messageBottom);
              
                panel2.Visible = true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Could you please provide a screen shot of desired result?

Comment: Hello, I need same functionality like skype. You when chat on skype. It does not load all chats. It loads as you scroll up.

Comment: Ok, I got that point but I do not have skype and do not know what it is look like. So, providing a screen shot may help a lot to understand.

Comment: Well not sure I may be able to paste skype image because of copy right issues but let me explain. I want when a user open the chat with the receiver assuming they had chatted before like from last year. I dont want to show all conversation from last year. I want on the table layout to show previously chat like from yesterday not showing all chat from last year. So What I want is as the user scroll up on the tablelayoutpane the table layout pane get added previous chats. Eg if user scrolls like up to Aug 2023 what is displayed on the pane is chat from Aug to date not other previous chats.

Comment: Then handle MouseWheel event, and load x records for each event.

Comment: Show me example code on how to do that. Am not that good in C#

Comment: Check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: [You can handle the Endscroll event of the scrollbar of the control to know when to load more.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58025866/3585500)

Comment: If you don't want to wait for the table to scroll to the end before loading more, you can use the OnCellPaint event to test if a near bottom row has become visible. [The TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs can give you the cell's row and column.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutcellpainteventargs?view=netframework-4.8.1)